# Is it possible to vary the number of flex-items shown based on layout?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a thumbnail gallery preview that I'm displaying using flex-box.  It works great, with my only gripe being that I sometimes end up with incomplete rows depending on the current width of the responsive layout.

On my laptop display, I end up with 2 rows of 5 columns, 10 in total.  On a smaller display it drops down to 3 columns, so I have a pretty grid of 3 x 3 thumbs with a single lonely thumb left on the fourth row.

I'd like to omit any incomplete rows.  I know I could do it with some (quite fiddly, I imagine) javascript, but a CSS solution would be better.

Is there a flex-box trick that I'm missing?

Comment: Does the amount of columns you have vary? And would you like for the *last* columns to be hidden? Does your layout *always* assume 5 columns / 3 columns? Actually, can you show us an example?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It's a small panel that (on an ideal display) always shows 10 thumbnails, in a 2 x 5 grid.  As the screen size shrinks the panel shrinks and I end up with only 3 columns, instead of 5.

Comment: But yes, it can end up as anything of 5/4/3/2 columns, 3 was just an example.

Comment: I think I have a solution, can you share your current working code?

Comment: Not easily, but I can hack it out later on today if needed.

Comment: In that case, can you share the basic structure of a single column, as well as your media queries?

Comment: No media queries, or columns as such.  It's just a min-width/max-width div with a display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap `<ul>` with 10 `<li>` inside it, each one with a square thumbnail `<img>` in it!

Comment: This is probably the solution you'll have to go after http://jsfiddle.net/HdfaT/602/

Comment: That'll have to do, thanks @Roberrrt - put as an actual answer if you want some invisible internet points

Comment: Can you explain to me the purpose of the `li:first-child:nth-last-child(10),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(10) ~ li` rule?  The demo seems to work just as well if I replace all of that with a simple `li`, but I feel I'm missing something clever... :)

Comment: I've come up with my own solution (answered below) that better fits my needs now @Roberrrt - thanks again for your time though!

Comment: I didnt even read the other comments, sorry! Here's my source on the matter: http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to @Roberrrt for his comments on the original question.  While his solution did what was asked of it, I decided that riddling my code with numerous media queries in the CSS was (a) annoying in the first place and (b) downright unmaintainable down the line.  And actually, if we consider user zooming/font size changes etc, it just doesn't really work.

So I've bitten the bullet, and accept that javascript is the correct solution.

Maybe this will be useful to someone else, so I'm sharing it here.  It's quite specific to my needs, but should be easy for someone else to adapt or generalise if needed.

```
var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
var li      = gallery.getElementsByTagName('li');
var liL     = li.length;

// this next count is necessary as my gallery outputs about 20 empty
// <li> elements (with 0 height) to avoid the ugly case involving
// justify:space-between and an incomplete final row.
//
// Although THIS code is here to REMOVE those last items, it's still
// nice to have the empty <li>s for anyone browsing without javascript.
var liFilledL = gallery.querySelectorAll('li>a').length;

var cols = 0;
var leftMax = 0;

// loop through the <li>s checking that they have a height and that
// each one is to the right of the one before.  Thus we count how many
// exist in the top row.
for (var i = 0; i < liL; i++) {
    if (li[i].offsetHeight) {
        if (li[i].offsetLeft < leftMax) {
            break;
        }

        cols++;
        leftMax = li[i].offsetLeft;
    }
}

// given how many filled <li> there are, and how many are in the top
// row, we can calculate the index of the first <li> in the incomplete
// row
var firstToHide = Math.floor(liFilledL / cols) * cols;

// then simply loop through and hide them.
for (var i = firstToHide; i < liL; i++) {
    li[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

For performance reasons I'll probably just run this on page load, as it's not essential that it's recomputed on page resize.  Wrapping it in a debounced resize event handler is obviously an option though, if needed.

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you for posting this! I try to minimize my use of JavaScript when there's no tag, so I explored pure CSS solutions. It's a good one though.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough - I had hoped that it'd be possible with CSS, and as you demonstrated, it was.  The JS seems worth the sacrifice in this instance though.  Like you I generally try to avoid it when I can.